# How can I allow guest Amplify users to download files from my S3 bucket using the AWS Amplify iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

I have set up a bucket on Amazon AWS using the Amplify, CLI console. I've followed the documentation for the Amplify iOS SDK, and have the following setup code on the iOS app:

```
do {
    try Amplify.add(plugin: AWSCognitoAuthPlugin())
    try Amplify.add(plugin: AWSS3StoragePlugin())
    try Amplify.configure()
} catch {
    print(message: "An error occurred setting up Amplify: \(error)")
}
```

When I try to download a resource I get the following error:

```
StorageError: The HTTP response status code is [403].
```

I am using the following code:

```
var url: URL = //url to download to
var key: String = //key for the file as specified in S3

operation = Amplify.Storage.downloadFile(key: key,
                                         local: url) { [weak self] progress in
    guard let _ = self else { return }
    print(message: "progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
} resultListener: { [weak self] result in
    guard let _ = self else { return }
    switch result {
    case .success:
        print(message: "success!")
    case .failure(let error):
        print(message: "error: \(error)")
    }
}
```

The user I set up via `amplify configure` has `AdministratorAccess` and `AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess` policies attached:

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: What are the credentials you're using? What roles are associated with that IAM user?

Comment: I am using guest access as per this documentation: 
https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/guest_access/q/platform/ios/

Comment: The permissions for this guest user are set for AdministratorAccess and AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess

Comment: Are you sure the file definitely exists? Output the key and bucket and make sure the key contains any sub folders etc. and the casing is correct etc.

Comment: Have you modified the S3 bucket's ACL? Have you added any bucket policies?

Comment: The files are definitely there. There are no subfolders, so the key looks like: "filename.zip". I've not updated ACL or policies. On the bucket the bucket policy is blank. ACL access has full access for owner and nothing for everything else. This is true for both the bucket and files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user-created via `amplify configure` is used by Amplify for provisioning of resources -  you've assigned `AdministratorAccess` and `AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess` policies to your Amplify user but not to the *unauthenticated user* role, which is what is used by Amplify guest users.

---

Find the role name for the unauthenticated role first, by signing in to the [Amazon Cognito console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/cognito/home), choose **Manage Identity Pools**, and then select the identity pool that was created by Amplify.

Click **Edit identity pool** in the top right-hand side of the page & you'll see a page similar to the below, with a drop-down box labelled **Unauthenticated role**:

[image]

The current role being used for guest/unauthenticated users will be in the dropdown.

Lookup the role name inside the IAM console & then attach the AWS-managed `AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess` policy to the role.

---

Your unauthenticated users should now have access to read files from the S3 buckets & you should no longer get a `403 Access Denied` error.